# GROK pattern not returning results

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am very new to ELK and I am stuck at extracting fields.Below is the sample data

```
Dec 9 06:36:01 s-login-01 CRON[2436102]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user mXXt

Dec 9 06:34:07 s-login-01 sshd[2424671]: Disconnected from user sw 10.xx.1x.xx port 4000

Dec 9 06:34:05 s-login-01 systemd-logind[2405]: Session 20923 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
```

I have the above sample data I want to know how to write the .conf file for this .I tried using the below .conf but It did not extract the fields.

```
input {
file {
path => "/../syslog.log"
type => "syslog"
start_position => beginning
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}
}
filter {
grok {

    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:HOST}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:PROCESS}\[%{NUMBER:PID}\]\:%{GREEDYDATA:activity}" }
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:HOST}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:PROCESS}\[%{NUMBER:PID}\]\:%{GREEDYDATA:activity}.?*%{WORD:User}" }
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:HOST}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:PROCESS}\[%{NUMBER:PID}\]\:%{GREEDYDATA:activity}.?*%{WORD:User}.?*%{IP:IP}.?*%{NUMBER:Port}" }
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:HOST}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:PROCESS}\[%{NUMBER:PID}\]\:%{GREEDYDATA:activity}.?*%{NUMBER:Session_ID}" }
}
}
output {
Elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "sample_"
}
}
```

Comment: Do you need the grok patterns for all the three sample data ?? Or You need a single grok pattern  that satisfies your sample data ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the single grok pattern that satisfies all the sample data you provided:

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP} %{DATA:HOST} %{DATA:PROCESS}\[%{BASE10NUM:PID}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:MSG}
```

I have used the [GROK DEBUGGER](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to create the grok pattern.

Here is the output:
[image]

---

Find below the grok pattern for individual sample data:

**Dec 9 06:34:07 s-login-01 sshd[2424671]: Disconnected from user sw 10.xx.1x.xx port 4000**

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP} %{DATA:HOST} %{DATA:PROCESS}\[%{BASE10NUM:PID}\]: %{DATA:ACTIVITY} %{DATA:msg} user %{DATA:USER} %{IP:IPADDRESS} %{DATA:msg} %{BASE10NUM:PORT}
```

**Dec 9 06:36:01 s-login-01 CRON[2436102]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user mXXt**

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP} %{DATA:HOST} %{DATA:PROCESS}\[%{BASE10NUM:PID}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:ACTIVITY} user %{WORD:USER}
```

**Dec 9 06:34:05 s-login-01 systemd-logind[2405]: Session 20923 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.**

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP} %{DATA:HOST} %{DATA:PROCESS}\[%{BASE10NUM:PID}\]: Session %{BASE10NUM:SESSION_ID} %{GREEDYDATA:ACTIVITY}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but  the GROK you mentioned will not extract User field in sample event  1,2. Also ..  there is port and IP in sample 2 and session id in sample event 3... I want to extract all these fields based on the type of event

Comment: @Vine I have provided the exact answer. Will you please use the respective grok pattern I provided in answer to test it out with your sample data. Thanks 

Comment: I did test that..but it did not work....I am trying to achieve multiple field extractions ..for instance ..after user there is sw...which should be extracted as user field and the IP address following should be IP and the port should be "PORT" field but your grok extracts all that as greedy data
Dec 9 06:34:07 s-login-01 sshd[2424671]: Disconnected from user sw 10.xx.1x.xx port 4000

Comment: For which sample data you need multiple field extractions, please paste in comment and I will check on that. @Vine

Answer (score 0):

you must set such as this i thing the pattern of match you have mistake

```html
input {
        file {

        path => "/root/mult.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        codec => multiline{

                 pattern => "^ -%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
                 negate => true
                 what => "previous"
        }
}
 }
filter {
    grok {
     match => [
       "message", "(?m)^ -%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{DATA:mydata}\n(\t)?%{GREEDYDATA:stack}",
       "message", "^ -%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{WORD:main}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\(%{JAVACLASS:class}\) %{GREEDYDATA:mydata}" ]
        break_on_match => false
 }
    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
 }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug}
elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
  }
}
```